# Downloading image from the web with imagemagick and saving to parse

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, underscore.js, fs

I'm able to download the image using http and and I am able to resize it using imagemagic, but I can't figure out how to upload it to Parse. Parse only lets me upload: an array of byte value numbers OR base64 string. What I'm confused on is how I can convert the stdout to base64 string so that I can upload it to parse. I tried using fs, but to no avail. I just keep getting errors when it tries to read the file and convert it. What is wrong with my code?

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var url = require("url");
var srcUrl = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JxwwGtquGqw/maxresdefault.jpg';
var http = srcUrl.charAt(4) == 's' ? require("https") : require("http");
var im = require('imagemagick');

var Image = require("parse-image");
var image_card_2x = [540, 350];

var thumb = '';
var fs = require('fs');

var request = http.get(url.parse(srcUrl), function(response) {
    console.log("got data");
    var data = '';

    response.setEncoding('binary');

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });


    console.log("data is " + data);
    response.on('end', function () {

        // var image = new Image();
        // image.setData(response.buffer);
        // image.scale({
        //     width: image_card_2x,
        //     height: Math.floor((image.height() * arrayElement[0]) / image.width())
        // });
        // image.setFormat("JPEG");

        // console.log("about to make image");


        im.resize({
            srcData: data,
            width: 404,
            height: 269,
            format: 'jpg'
        }, function(err, buffer) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);

            var base64 = new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');

            var file = new Parse.File("maa.jpg", {
                base64: base64
            }); 

            console.log("about to save");
            var VideoLinks = Parse.Object.extend("VideoLinks");
            var videoLink = new VideoLinks();
            videoLink.set("image", file);

            return videoLink.save();

            console.log("saved");


            //fs.writeFileSync('kittens-resized.jpg', stdout, 'binary');
            console.log("worked!");
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: You should remove commented code, it won't help solving your problem and do so would reduce your example. [mcve]

Comment: I didn`t answer your question, rather tried to help you get a good answer. This is one way these comments are meant to be. You are welcome.